# Qual è il senso di "sistemato" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Anche per loro sono *il signorino*, entrando ho sentito che uno ce l’ha coi miei pullover. 
>       «Non sai chi è il signorino? Gialli bianchi azzurri, uno al giorno ne cambia, non puoi sbagliare, tutti colori così.» 
>       «Niente insinuazioni, atteniamoci all’odio di classe.» 
>       «Sentimento superato.» 
>       «Levami pure la *distrazione* di odiarlo, che mi rimane, solo le scarpe rotte?» 
>       Così sono **sistemato**. E le avesse almeno avute rotte le scarpe. Sono io invece ad averle rotte, un bel buco nascosto – fare attenzione alla gamba accavallata. Senza una lira, i pullover ormai ridotti a due o tre, avanzi del tempo passato, anche i colori sbiaditi, i soldi delle sigarette infilati in tasca da mammà, [...].

Ho letto tutte le accezioni della [voce "sistemare" sul vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sistemare). Tuttavia, non riesco a capire cosa voglia dire la frase "così sono sistemato" che appare nel testo. Qualcuno di voi lo saprebbe spiegare?

Comment: Il significato sembra essere “così sono ridotto” ...scarpe col buco, senza una lira etc. Accezione  informale, “*punire, mettere al proprio posto*” vedi def. 4 De Mauro https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/sistemare

Comment: Concordo che sia pertinente l'accezione “punire, mettere al proprio posto”, ma da questo non deduco “sono ridotto”. Credo che si riferisca invece a come è stato “messo al suo posto” dai personaggi che parlano prima, quasi come se dicesse: “loro hanno deciso chi sono, secondo loro la faccenda è conclusa”.

Comment: Come ha detto @DaG, anche a me sembra che "sistemato" non faccia riferimento a "scarpe col buco, senza una lira, etc." perché la frase che va dopo questo "sistemato" è "e le avesse almeno avute rotte le scarpe", che non fa riferimento al narratore, ma alla persona che ha detto "levami pure la *distrazione* di odiarlo, che mi rimane, solo le scarpe rotte?"

Comment: Riletto il testo più volte e anche le risposte, credo che il significato sia “così sono classificato”.

Comment: Bisognerebbe contattare La Capria (99enne ma vivo) o un suo esegeta (come Silvio Perrella, curatore dei due volumi dei Meridiani con le opere di La Capria) e chiederglielo, visto che questa domanda continua a ottenere risposte tutte diverse fra loro (qualche volta con più d'una ipotesi nella stessa risposta).

Answer (score 1):

Sistemare è un verbo molto interessante. Ha degli utilizzi canonici e altri colloquiali, in particolare ironici.

Nel primo caso significa mettere ordine, collocare in modo adeguato. Si può usare sia per le cose, *sistemare casa*, *sistemare una scatola nell'armadio*, che per le persone, *sistemare i parenti in un buon albergo*. Ci sono poi utilizzi colloquiali, sconsigliabili in un testo formale. *Ho sistemato mio figlio al ministero*, o spesso *ho piazzato*, significa procurare un lavoro. Va usato con cautela poiché tende anche a significare che il parlante si è attivato in modo poco ortodosso, magari scavalcando delle procedure. Usato in prima persona, salvo il contesto suggerisca altrimenti, *sono sistemato* significa *sono sistemato bene*, detto anche *sono a posto*, ossia sono in una situazione, collocazione comoda o piacevole.

Nell'ambito dell'uso colloquiale,  è frequente l'uso ironico, ed è facile che qui di ironia si tratti.
Leggendo il contesto, si capisce chiaramente che chi scrive è  economicamente piuttosto malridotto, perciò "sono sistemato" può ben intendersi come "sono sistemato male, messo male".

Non penso che si faccia del tutto torto alle intenzioni dell'autore  interpretando "così sono sistemato" come "questa è la mia attuale situazione" oppure "così sono ridotto", tuttavia è probabile che egli sottintenda qualcosa di diverso.

*Sistemare una persona*, detto da una parrucchiere, vuol dire mettergli i capelli in ordine, diversamente, detto da un malvivente(*), significa malmenarlo. In modo idiomatico, si dice *lo sistemo per le feste* o *lo concio per le feste* a significare che, al contrario, intendo rovinare l'acconciatura, e non solo, al malcapitato. Senza volgere a situazioni così estreme, *quello lì lo sistemo io*, manifesta l'intenzione di castigare, redarguire, dare noia o danno.

Nella narrazione, il verbo in analisi segue immediatamente i commenti di alcuni individui che non vedono di buon occhio l'altro soggetto, poiché lo avvertono come appartenente a una classe sociale contrapposta. Allora, "così sono sistemato" significherebbe "questa è la mia infelice situazione, costoro mi considerano un ricco e mi odiano, mentre io sono ben più povero di loro".

In entrambi i casi, si ravvisa ironia, essendo il soggetto *sistemato male*; tuttavia, nel primo caso, il disagio deriva dal versare in cattive condizioni economiche, nella seconda interpretazione, l'incomoda situazione nasce dall'odio da di chi esterna  i commenti.

Infine, alla luce delle frasi precedenti, è anche possibile che lo scrittore intenda usare il verbo *sistemare* in modo in modo non ironico, ma comunque traslato. Invero, proprio come posso sistemare, nel senso di collocare, un oggetto in un contenitore, posso anche per estensione collocare una persona in un determinato contesto sociale. In questo caso, chi fa i commenti colloca l'altro in una classe sociale abbiente, ancorché  in modo erroneo. In quest'ultima accezione, si significa "questo è il modo con cui vengo inquadrato", senza specifiche connotazioni negative o positive, ma semplicemente  come constatazione.

(*) Un malvivente vero utilizzerebbe un linguaggio molto più crudo, ma il cattivo di un fumetto per bambini può esprimersi così.

Answer (score 0):

Secondo me la frase significa "questa è la mia situazione".

Comment: Questo post appare nella coda di revisione di "low quality posts". Quindi, potresti aggiungere qualche particolare alla tua risposta? E, come ho detto in un commento precedente, la frase che va dopo questo "sistemato" è "e le avesse almeno avute rotte le scarpe", che non fa riferimento al narratore, ma alla persona che ha detto "levami pure la distrazione di odiarlo, che mi rimane, solo le scarpe rotte?". Dunque, non mi sembra molto coerente da parte del narratore dire "questa è la mia situazione", immediatamente dopo riferirsi a un'altra persona e poi dare i dettagli di questa sua situazione.

Comment: Dopo aver letto il commento di @DaG, mi sembra che il senso sia piuttosto qualcosa come "loro hanno deciso che sono *il signorino* che indossa un pullover di un colore diverso ogni giorno, degno di un sentimento di odio di classe". Non so se il “punire, mettere al proprio posto” che appare sul De Mauro si può interpretare come "classificare" una persona in questo modo o parlare di una persona in questo modo.

Comment: Credo che per dare un'interpretazione completa sarebbe necessario avere ancora più chiaro il contesto. Purtroppo non ho letto il romanzo, ma ho amici romani e napoletani che usano locuzioni simili (o identiche) per commentare sarcasticamente la loro situazione, soprattutto quando quest'ultima non è delle migliori.

Comment: Io ho letto il romanzo, ma non credo che ci sia più contesto da aggiungere che possa aiutare a capire il significato di questa espressione.

Answer (score 0):

Significa letteralmente "questa è la mia situazione/ la mia realtà / ciò che devo affrontare". Si riferisce, in quel contesto, al pensiero che gli altri hanno di lui. Che è in contrasto con quella che è la realtà spiegata dopo. In questo caso la frase "Così sono sistemato" è un ponte fra il pensiero degli altri personaggi contrapposto alla realtà del narratore. Ha in questo caso un'accezione autocommiserativa. Potrebbe essere tradotta anche con: "Ecco, visto che etichetta mi hanno messo addosso? Povero me. Questi non sanno in realtà che..." e infatti dopo quella frase comincia ad autocommiserarsi. In conclusione, è un modo elegante e sintetico per dire: "Questa è la mia situazione".

Comment: Mi sembra che tu dia due spiegazioni diverse, una delle quali condivido (la parafrasi dell'“Ecco, visto che etichetta...” etc.). Ma se è vero questo, non è vero al contempo che significa “Questa è la mia situazione”.

Answer (score 0):

Il verbo *sistemare* significa anche correggere, riparare, risolvere, sia in modo letterale che in modo ironico (cioé al contrario).

E si usa talvolta in senso traslato, riferito a una persona: "La sistemo io, quella!", con il significato eventualmente di castigo, o d'imposizione a quella persona di una scelta o situazione inizialmente non voluta o non prevista da quella persona.

Riferito al parlante stesso ("sono sistemato") può essere inteso in senso positivo oppure, di nuovo, ironico. In senso positivo, per esempio:

> Finalmente ho ottenuto quello che volevo, ora sono sistemato

In senso ironico:

> E' fallito pure quest'ultimo tentativo, ora sono proprio sistemato

Aggiungo che, nel testo dell'OP, la parola "così" nella frase "Così sono sistemato" può essere intesa come "Perciò (in conseguenza di questo) sono sistemato", oppure come "Sono sistemato in questo modo (espresso prima)". A me pare ambigua, forse leggendo molti più stralci dal libro il dubbio diminuirebbe.

Answer (score 0):

Citando la stessa Treccani che hai linkato, credo che la accezione che si avvicina di più sia:

> Nell’uso fam., dare una buona lezione, una punizione

Il suddetto *signorino* riceve una serie di "complimenti" che chiaramente lo feriscono, perciò il loro apparente odio finisce per dargli una metaforica lezione. Io lo intendo in un senso ironico, un po' come suggerisce [@linuxfan](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/13788/1042).

Comment: Non credo si tratti di compagni di classe. L'espressione "odio di classe" si riferisce a [questo](https://www.lastampa.it/politica/2007/01/06/news/e-il-poeta-disse-l-odio-di-classe-1.37134737).

Comment: @Charo fuori dal contesto non era chiaro, ma il resto è comunque valido.